# Error when pushing the readme.md file to GitHub

Tags: reactjs, github, repository, push, root

I updated the readme.md file. Which is located on the file before. I just updated the file. But when I tried to push to GitHub. It shows error. that the file can not be pushed. It is locally updated. What can I do now?

Comment: What kind of error do you have? We need know more informations.